# How to make overlay control above all other controls?

Tags: wpf, xaml, controls, overlay

I need to make a control appear above all other controls, so it will partially overlay them.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

If you are using a `Canvas` or `Grid` in your layout, give the control to be put on top a higher `ZIndex`.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.zindex.aspx):

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" WindowTitle="ZIndex Sample">
  <Canvas>
    <Rectangle Canvas.ZIndex="3" Width="100" Height="100" Canvas.Top="100" Canvas.Left="100" Fill="blue"/>
    <Rectangle Canvas.ZIndex="1" Width="100" Height="100" Canvas.Top="150" Canvas.Left="150" Fill="yellow"/>
    <Rectangle Canvas.ZIndex="2" Width="100" Height="100" Canvas.Top="200" Canvas.Left="200" Fill="green"/>

    <!-- Reverse the order to illustrate z-index property -->

    <Rectangle Canvas.ZIndex="1" Width="100" Height="100" Canvas.Top="300" Canvas.Left="200" Fill="green"/>
    <Rectangle Canvas.ZIndex="3" Width="100" Height="100" Canvas.Top="350" Canvas.Left="150" Fill="yellow"/>
    <Rectangle Canvas.ZIndex="2" Width="100" Height="100" Canvas.Top="400" Canvas.Left="100" Fill="blue"/>
  </Canvas>
</Page>
```

If you don't specify `ZIndex`, the children of a panel are rendered in the order they are specified (i.e. last one on top).

If you are looking to do something more complicated, you can look at how `ChildWindow` is implemented in Silverlight. It overlays a semitransparent background and popup over your entire `RootVisual`.

Comment: Note: This is not like the HTML Canvas like I expected. It's not meant for direct drawing, but provides an absolute positioning context (that you would usually directly put shapes into).

Comment: why WebBrowser tag allways in above all childrens either when i use Canvas or Grid

Answer (score 94):

[Robert Rossney](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450985/how-to-make-overlay-control-above-all-other-controls/5451095#5451095) has a good solution. Here's an alternative solution I've used in the past that separates out the "Overlay" from the rest of the content. This solution takes advantage of the attached property `Panel.ZIndex` to place the "Overlay" on top of everything else. You can either set the Visibility of the "Overlay" in code or use a `DataTrigger`.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

 <Grid x:Name="Overlay" Panel.ZIndex="1000" Visibility="Collapsed">
    <Grid.Background>
      <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity=".5"/>
    </Grid.Background>

    <!-- Add controls as needed -->
  </Grid>

  <!-- Use whatever layout you need -->
  <ContentControl x:Name="MainContent" />

</Grid>
```

Comment: This overlay will cover the entire window, not just a specific area.

Comment: The best solution ever! Thank you!

Comment: Exactly what I needed to lay a "privacy screen" over my entire app window (e.g. to hide sensitive info if user walks away from his desk), with very little code. Awesome!

Answer (score 44):

Controls in the same cell of a Grid are rendered back-to-front.  So a simple way to put one control on top of another is to put it in the same cell.

Here's a useful example, which pops up a panel that disables everything in the view (i.e. the user control) with a busy message while a long-running task is executed (i.e. while the `BusyMessage` bound property isn't null):

```
<Grid>

    <local:MyUserControl DataContext="{Binding}"/>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                <Setter Property="Visibility"
                        Value="Visible" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BusyMessage}"
                                 Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility"
                                Value="Collapsed" />
                    </DataTrigger>

                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Style>
        <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                Background="DarkGray"
                Opacity=".7" />
        <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Background="White"
                Padding="20"
                BorderBrush="Orange"
                BorderThickness="4">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding BusyMessage}" />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 25):

Put the control you want to bring to front at the end of your xaml code. I.e.

```
<Grid>
  <TabControl ...>
  </TabControl>
  <Button Content="ALways on top of TabControl Button"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 18):

This is a common function of [Adorners](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/adorners-overview) in WPF. Adorners typically appear above all other controls, but the other answers that mention z-order may fit your case better.

Example:

In the control's constructor:

```
Loaded += (sender, args) =>
{
    AdornerLayer adornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(this);
    GreenOverlayAdorner adorner = new GreenOverlayAdorner(this);
    adornerLayer.Add(adorner);
};
```

GreenOverlayAdorner.cs

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Media;

public class GreenOverlayAdorner : Adorner
{
    public GreenOverlayAdorner(UIElement adornedElement)
        : base(adornedElement)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        Rect adornedElementRect = new Rect(this.AdornedElement.RenderSize);

        // Draw semi-transparent green background
        Brush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, 0, 255, 0)); // 50% transparent green
        drawingContext.DrawRectangle(brush, null, adornedElementRect);

        // Draw solid green line
        Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.Green, 2);
        drawingContext.DrawLine(pen, adornedElementRect.TopLeft, adornedElementRect.BottomRight);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<Canvas Panel.ZIndex="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="570">
  <!-- YOUR XAML CODE -->
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Panel.ZIndex. for example you want to block mouse movement on cefsharp chromium web browser.

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid x:Name="gridBlockMovement" Panel.ZIndex="1000" Opacity="0.01" Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        <cef:ChromiumWebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser" Panel.ZIndex="1"></cef:ChromiumWebBrowser>
    </Grid>
```