# How to put a richtextbox ON an image in xaml?

Tags: image, xaml, richtextbox

I am trying to put a richtextbox on an image,whose opacity is reduced to 0.8,if that matters.
Now, I want a richtextbox OVER the image to display some information downloaded constantly. I have richtextbox ready,but design view is not allowing me to put richtextbox on the image,image slides downwards. I have gone through all properties of richtextbox,changed them one by one,none worked. How can I do this? 
In other way, maybe I want to know how to put controls over one other?Couldn't find much on msdn too...

Comment: Found Similar thread anyways.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450985/how-to-make-overlay-control-above-all-other-controls

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a TextBox (scrolling)  over an Image.  It should work with a RichTextBox.

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{StaticResource yourImage}" Opacity=".3">
            <ImageBrush.RelativeTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX=".5" ScaleY=".5" CenterX=".5" CenterY=".5"/>
            </ImageBrush.RelativeTransform>
        </ImageBrush>
    </Grid.Background>                   
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <TextBlock  x:Name="YourTextBox" Grid.Row="1" Background="Transparent"  Margin="3,6,3,0" Text="{Binding YourMessage}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```