# WPF Detect UserControl beeing covered / not displayed

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, visual-tree

If I have a `Usercontrol`, which is overlayed by another control (a `Grid` for example), is there an event or trigger to find out that the `UserControl` is currently covered by something? Maybe an event from VisualTree or some kind of listener?

[image]

Comment: You can use Panel.ZIndex property to place UserControl on top.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450985/how-to-make-overlay-control-above-all-other-controls

Comment: I don't want to place the UserControl on top, I want an event if the UserControl is covered by another control.

Comment: Can you use Panel.GetZIndex? Also, what action would your code perform in response to the event?

Comment: No this whon't work I think. Im trying to solve the Airspace Problem when using a HWND. I think a possible Solution would be to detect if the control is covered somehow and then show a Bitmap Image instead.