# XAML ListView - Stack items over each other

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone, microsoft-metro, windows-10

How can you have a ListView (or similar Object) stack its items **over** each other.
Like a real-life stack of newspaper or post cards.

Comment: where do I place this property?
Just in the ItemsTemplate?
How can I bind the Z-Index to the ListItem Index?

Comment: Perhaps use the `ItemContainerStyle` to set a negative margin on each of the items so they overlap. You may also need to overwrite the `ItemsPanelTemplate` to use panel that allows overlapping children... I'm not sure if a StackPanel allows it by default.

Comment: Not Sure may Help [Check This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5450993/2470362)

Comment: I am programming a game, with a stack of cards. I want to have a fade away animation, when a new card is picked.
There may be a lot of cards (like 50-70), so the margin approach may not be scalable.
It would be fine to have them over each other at the same spot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.Items>
        <TextBlock Text="hallo" />
        <TextBlock Text="welt" />
    </ItemsControl.Items>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want items to overlap, you can simply set a negative margin.

For instance, with a simple `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="ListView" Margin="5 75 5 0">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0 -65 0 0" Background="White" CornerRadius="10" Height="80">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

And the render:

[image]

The same result can be achieved with a `ListView`, though it can be slightly more annoying since you may have to tweak the control's default margins.