# Two control(Tabcontrol & Grid) shown cut when partly overwrapped

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, grid

As normal, I have main big Grid for Window(WPF) and there're 2 Tabcontrol which has each DataGrid inside.
And now I'd like to make 1 minor Grid which include DataGrid inside main big Grid like a vertical bridge from above Tabcontrol to below Tabcontrol.
However, I'm getting the minor Grid shown cut by overwrapping with 2 Tabcontrol as you can see in the attached screen capture image. (Blue color is for newly added minor grid and yellow color is for DataGrid inside minor grid)

How Can I get a minor Grid fully shown not interfered by other controls?
(Because late night here, I'm going to sleep and will reply tomorrow. Thank you so much !)

[image]

Comment: Please show the xaml for these controls.

Comment: @dev1998, Many thanks for your care. I've found my simple solution as self-answered here. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the people who are looking for solutions, I share mine that setting higher Zindex. If needed, More details are on [How to make overlay control above all other controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450985/how-to-make-overlay-control-above-all-other-controls)