# C# WPF XAML In Window Messages Boxes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

[image]

I am new to C# WPF, I have created a `Popup` window which contains a `DataGrid` to hold some data. In certain cases if there are any errors in the data I want to display this error in the same popup window at the bottom of the window (See screenshot). The idea is that the user can then click ok and the message will disappear displaying the full datagrid again.

Does anybody know how to do this?

I do not want another popup message box in a separate window, I want all messages to be displayed/stacked in the same pop window as the datagrid.

Comment: following link will help you in overlapping message contaainer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450985/how-to-make-overlay-control-above-all-other-controls then hide the container by `visibility="collapsed"` on button click

Answer (score 0):

Below, there are 2 grids in the XAML:  There is is the master grid, which contains the `DataGrid`, and another grid which contains the error UI.  The error grid is normally collapsed (`Visibility` set to `Visibility.Collapsed`).

When the error message needs to be shown, the error grid's `Visibility` is set to `Visibility.Visible`, which shows the grid.  When the user clicks on the "Dismiss" button, the error grid's `Visibility` is set to `Visibility.Collapsed`.

There is not a separate window or popup.  Everything is contained within the master view.

XAML:

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <DataGrid>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Show Message Window" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
    <!-- This is the "error grid"-->
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="Auto" 
       Background="AliceBlue" Visibility="Collapsed" Name="grdError">
      <TextBlock Text="Oops.  This is an error!"/>
      <Button Content="Dismiss" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="Button_Click_3"/>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
```

Code Behind:

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      grdError.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      grdError.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. Let me try this!