# Render ItemsControl item ContentPresenters on top of each other

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a view model containing an observable collection property:

```
public ObservableCollection<ExplorerPane> Panes { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ExplorerPane>();
```

In the user control corresponding to my view model, I am using `Panes` as the `ItemsSource` to an `ItemsControl` and just using a `ContentPresenter` to display the content of each `ExplorerPane`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Panes}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The catch is that I want the content presenters to render their panes *on top of each other*, so that only one is visible at a time.

I have thought of a solution along these lines: ["Controls in the same cell of a Grid are rendered back-to-front. So a simple way to put one control on top of another is to put it in the same cell."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5451095/1973097)

My question then is how do I get the content presenters to be in the same cell of a grid?

Comment: If you only want to show a single ExplorerPane, add a `CurrentPane` property to your view model, and show it by `<ContentControl Content={Binding CurrentPane}"/>`

Comment: This suggestion works; if you update your answer I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Grid as ItemsPanel:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Panes}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

The ItemTemplate isn't necessary, because an ItemsControl already uses a ContentPresenter as item container.

---

However, if you only want to show a single ExplorerPane, add a `CurrentPane` property to your view model, and show it by

```
<ContentControl Content={Binding CurrentPane}"/>
```